# Drop all rows in a group if a condition is not satisfied

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I need to drop the groupby `city` and `district` rows, based on values of `pct`, say if I want drop out if there are `pct` is out of thresh `-100` or `100`.

For example, we can see `a` and `d` group has a `pct` value `-627.44` which is lower than `-100`, so we droped all `a` and `d` rows. Similarly, we can see for `b` and `e` has a `pct` value `139.77`, so we drop them as well.

```
  city district     date  price     pct
0    a        d  2020-01   2.42  -32.06
1    a        d  2020-02   1.43  -41.07
2    a        d  2020-03   0.27  -81.19
3    a        d  2020-04  -1.42 -627.44   # fail, drop all "a"
4    b        e  2020-03   2.14  -21.71
5    b        e  2020-04   1.14  -46.91   
6    b        e  2020-05  -0.45  139.77   # fail, drop all "b"
7    c        f  2020-04   4.59  -22.26
8    c        f  2020-05   2.33  -49.13
```

The desired output will look like this. How can I do that? Thank you.

```
  city district     date  price    pct
0    c        f  2020-04   4.59 -22.26
1    c        f  2020-05   2.33 -49.13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean condition and broadcast it to all rows per group using `GroupBy.transform`:

```
df[(df['pct'].between(-100, 100)).groupby(df['city']).transform('all')] 

  city district     date  price    pct
7    c        f  2020-04   4.59 -22.26
8    c        f  2020-05   2.33 -49.13
```

The result of `transform` will tell you which groups satisfy this condition:

```
(df['pct'].between(-100, 100)).groupby(df['city']).transform('all')

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
8     True
Name: pct, dtype: bool
```

You'd then use this to filter df.

---

```
(df.loc[(df['pct'].between(-100, 100)).groupby(df['city']).transform('all')] 
   .reset_index(drop=True))

  city district     date  price    pct
0    c        f  2020-04   4.59 -22.26
1    c        f  2020-05   2.33 -49.13
```

Comment: Thank you. Does `between` include `-100` and `100`?

Comment: @ahbon Yes, it includes both bounds. If you want to include one and exclude the other you can create the condition yourself: `((df['a'] >= lower) & (df['a'] < higher))` instead of `df['a'].between(lower, higher)`.

Comment: yes, but you can use `.between(-100,100,inclusive = False)` if you don't want it

Comment: @ansev That excludes both bounds, there's no way to include one and exclude the other using `between`. But yes, what you said too.

Comment: both answers complement each other :)

Comment: I get a `KeyError: ('city', 'district')` with my real data, it's weird.

Comment: @ahbon Did you accidentally do `df['a', 'b']` instead of `df[['a', 'b']]`?

Comment: You mean changed to this `(df.loc[(df['pct'].between(-100, 100)).groupby(df[['city', 'district']]).transform('all')] 
   .reset_index(drop=True))`? It generates: `ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional`

Comment: @ahbon Ah, didn't understand what you were trying to do initially, but the solution is to pass a list of series to the grouper.  `.groupby([ df['city'], df['district'], ])`

Answer (score 2):

or we can use [`GroupBy.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df.groupby(['city','district']).filter(lambda x: (x['pct'].between(-100,100)).all())
```

**Output**

```
  city district     date  price    pct
0    c        f  2020-04   4.59 -22.26
1    c        f  2020-05   2.33 -49.13
```

Comment: I get an `Empty DataFrame`, any ideas? In fact, it shouldn't be, because all value is in the bounds.

Comment: I get it, because there are `NaN`s in `pct`, I use `df['pct'] = df['pct'].replace(np.nan, 0)`, then it's OK.

Comment: you could use :`df['pct'] = df['pct'].fillna(0)` for it